# Do the C compiler know when a statement operates on a file and thus has "observable behaviour"?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, standard-library, side-effects

The C99 standard 5.1.2.3$2 says

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all side effects, 12) which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment. Evaluation of an expression in general includes both value
>   computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation for an lvalue expression
>   includes determining the identity of the designated object.

I guess that in a lot of cases the compiler can't inline and possibly eliminate the functions doing I/O since they live in a different translation unit. And the parameters to functions doing I/O are often pointers, further hindering the optimizer.

- But link-time-optimization gives the compiler "more to chew on".
- And even though the paragraph I quoted says that "modifying an object" (that's standard-speak for memory) is a side-effect, stores to memory is not automatically treated as a side effect when the optimizer kicks in. Here's an example from [John Regehrs Nine Ways to Break your Systems Software using Volatile](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/28) where the `message` store is reordered relative to the volatile `ready` variable.

.

```
volatile int ready;

int message[100];
void foo (int i) {
   message[i/10] = 42;
   ready = 1;
}
```

How do a C compiler determine if a statement operates on a file? In a free-standing embedded environment I declare registers as volatile, thus hindering the compiler from optimizing calls away and swapping order of I/O calls.

Is that the only way to tell the compiler that we're doing I/O? Or do the C standard dictate that these N calls in the standard library do I/O and thus must  receive special treatment? But then, what if someone created their own system call wrapper for say read?

Comment: What makes you think that a compiler does know?

Comment: @Yunnosch Right, maybe it doesn't know. I've updated the title. I probably should distinguish between observable behavior and side effects as well.

Answer (score 3):

As C has no statement dedicated to IO, only function calls can modify files. So if the compiler sees no function call in a sequence of statements, it knows that this sequence has not modified any file.

If only functions from the standard library are called, and if the environment is hosted, the compiler *could* know what they do and use that to guess what will happen.

But what is really important, is that the compiler only needs to respect side effects. It is perfectly allowed when it does not know, to assume that a function call could involve side effects and act accordingly. It will not be a violation of the standard if no side effects are actually involved, it will just possibly lose a higher optimization.

Comment: But what if say the whole read function is inlined? Is there something prohibiting that from happening?

Comment: @DanielNäslund Nothing prevents an optimizing compiler to look for other sources if it can find them and deduce whether a function call will modify files or not. Simply it is not required to do so. And even if the function is declared to be inlined, it is not required to use that to guess whether IO will be used. It is only required to process all actual file modifications as side effects, but can process whatever it want as if side effects could be involved in order to be simpler and super safe. Simply it will produce less efficient code...